# How to get number of lines in a MemoEdit control that has wrapping enabled?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a MemoEdit control with wrapping feature on.
The MemoEdit works in such way that the line breaks that the user sees are only cosmetic, so if the user didn't pressed the 'Enter' key by himself, the Lines property will return 1 (1 line was entered).

My goal is to retrieve the number of lines which the user sees (with the wrapping)
and if possible, also getting the place in which the cosmetic line break was inserted so i will be able to create a list of string that hold the lines the user sees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- You can get number of lines by :

Declare : `SendMessage` and `EM_LINEFROMCHAR`

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("User32.DLL")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam);

public const int EM_LINEFROMCHAR = 0xC9;
```

and get number of lines with :

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit).GetField("_maskBox", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextBoxMaskBox textBox = (DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextBoxMaskBox)fi.GetValue(memoEdit1);
int linecount = SendMessage(textBox.Handle, EM_LINEFROMCHAR, textBox.MaskBoxText.Length-1, 0)+1;
```

2- You can create list of string that hold the lines of MemoEdit, like this :

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit).GetField("_maskBox", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextBoxMaskBox textBox = (DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextBoxMaskBox)fi.GetValue(memoEdit1);
var lines = new List<string>();
for (int line = 0; ; line++)
{
    var start = textBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line);
    if (start < 0) break;
    var end = textBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(line + 1);
    if (end == -1 || start == end) end = textBox.MaskBoxText.Length;
    lines.Add(textBox.MaskBoxText.Substring(start, end - start));
}
```

Comment: HI, the Lines count isn't helpful because when wrapping is enabled and the user inputs many characters without pressing "Enter", the lines count will always be 1.

Comment: Ok! i'understand, I have change answer. you can test it!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Thank you too :)